# Intellij create Artifacts (JAR) together with Project build

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Is there a quick option to Build the Artifacts (Like JAR) with the Project Builds?
Instead of use BUILD->BUILD ARTIFACTS->BUILD

Thank you all

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html I hope thats what you're looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720269/how-to-build-artifacts-from-intellij-via-command-line. In the bottom section of run config window, there is task window(named Before Launch) in which you can add artifact build

Comment: Do you mean is auto build artifacts on run/debug Project or Project Builds (ctl+F9)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go Project Settings => Artifacts => Chose an artifact => Check to "Include in project build" box (image bellow).
Click "Apply" and the artifact will build together with your project build.

[image: config auto build artifacts]

Comment: What does ""Include in project build"" do?